# Why does google and the Alliance for Open Media make their own video codec, when there are open source encoders for h265

Tags: video-streaming, licensing, libx265

I read that google and the Alliance for Open Media are making their own codecs (vp9/av1) because of outrageous licencing costs for h265, but i saw that there are open source x265 encoders, that are licenced under gpl v2, so that makes x265 free to use, no?

Then why are google and the Alliance for Open Media making there own codecs?

Comment: GPL2 means free to use but perhaps the Alliance for Open Media don't want to give out the source code for their own stuff (which GPL2 would require)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about the encoding software (encoder), it's about using the encoding algorithm (which is patented) to encode content into a software that is used to re-produce it's information electronically and pass these bits of information along. This re-production of the work is governed by a body that actually not only takes license fees but also controls the use of the that-encoded information.

Inventing your own video codec makes you independent to control from others in that extend.

Comment: The [GPLv2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.txt) says "For example, if a patent
license would not permit royalty-free redistribution of the Program by
all those who receive copies directly or indirectly through you, then
the only way you could satisfy both it and this License would be to
refrain entirely from distribution of the Program." If one is allowed to distribute the implementation of patented algorithm without permission, why can't they sell patented hardware that their customers aren't allowed to operate?

Answer (score 1):

The software and the patents are not the same thing. On the decoder side, HEVC is free for the first 100,000 downloads/devices. For every download/device over, you must pay $.20 to mpegLA, or you are violating the license. The encoding side is usually free, unless you charge, or put advertising on the content, then you must pay to license the patents.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding#Patent_licensing

Comment: It would be interesting to know the official position of the alliance on patents and licences. Will they never ask money to use any part of the technology? And then there is of course the danger that some third party claims patents on the tech used in the alliance's new codecs.

Comment: from aomedia.org "AOMedia Video – pursues a new, *royalty-free* video codec"

Answer (score 0):

It is the *format* that is patented, not the *implementation*. The licensing of each has nothing to do with each other.

Every implementation of the format, whether it be software or hardware, paid or gratis, free or proprietary, is bound by the inescapable obligation to comply with whatever the patent holders demand. That is how patents work. In this case, the patent holders are asking for a per-copy fee.

If your implementor has taken the responsibility to pay all the patent holders for you, then you're all fine – you've already paid through the purchase price. But if nobody wants to do you this favor (because there is no purchase price), then this legal obligation is actually on you, the user! There are 3 patent pools to pay in this case, currently 2.23 $/copy would keep MPEG-LA and HEVC Advance happy, and Technicolor, you are supposed to negotiate a price with…

So let's say you are in the rather common situation that you need to enable a Linux distribution's *"restricted"* repository, in order to see a video of your friend's cat, and you wonder what *"may be illegal in some countries"* means: It means that nobody is paying the patent holders, and nobody cares, but it is illegal nontheless, in theory.